# Calculate confidence-level in A/B-test on revenue

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

I'm doing a split-test and need to calculate the confidence-level of the result. I need to implement the calculations on my own, not using any online-tools or excel.

I managed to do this for binomial values like the conversion rate, but couldn't get any further with non-binomial values like the revenue.

I have a lot of "old" data which I can use to calculate mean, variance, standard deviation and standard error specific for my data. I found some answers here, but (to be honsest) wasn't able to understand how to translate them into code. So any additional help is welcome.

Comment: Can you use R (downloadable and free)?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately not: I need something that works on a webserver, like PHP. But I might be able to convert it to PHP if I see a solution in R or another language.